# Function to manipulate a string ("abcdef" -> "faebdc")

Tags: c++, string

Hi everyone I'm working on a function to manipulating any string in this following manner.

"abc" -> "cab"

"abcd" -> "dacb"

"abcdef" -> "faebdc"

"divergenta" -> "adtinveerg"

... and so on.

This is the code I've come up with so far. I think it does the job but I think the code and solution is kind of ugly and I'm not sure if it's fail proof and if it is working properly for every given case. I would highly appreciate any input on this code or any examples on how you would write this function. I beg you to bear in mind that I'm very much a n00b so don't go **too** hard on me.

```
string transformer(string input) {

string temp;
int n = 0;
int m = (input.length() -1);

for( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

    temp += input[m];

    if (input[m] == input[n]) {
        break;
    }

    else {
        temp += input[n];
    }

    n += 1;
    m -= 1;

    if ( temp.length() == input.length() ) {
        break;
    }
}
return temp; }
```

Comment: So an edges-then-middle approach but starting from the back. Is this homework? If so, add the `homework` tag.

Comment: Because it is not reversing the string.

Comment: No this is not homework. Perhaps in the sense that I'm trying to learn c++ in my spare time but I'm not taking any class or having this as an assignment.

Comment: How about a recursive approach? `string xform(const string &s) { if (s.size() < 2) return s; else return s.lastChar + s.firstChar + xform(substring(s, 1, s.size-2)); };` - pseudocode in there but you'll get the gist...

Comment: In your last example, should it not be `adtinveegr`?

Comment: I don't understand the pattern _at all_.  _Why_ does abcd become dacb?

Comment: @MooingDuck Last, First, Last - 1, First + 1, Last - 2, First + 2...

Answer (score 2):

You have three problems.

Try it with "abbba". If the result isn't what you want, then this conditional:

```
if (input[m] == input[n]) {
break;
}
```

is just plain wrong.

Look at the other conditional:

```
if ( temp.length() == input.length() ) {
  break;
}
```

You're adding two characters at a time to `temp`. What if `input` has odd length?

Suppose that works correctly. Consider the loop:

```
for( int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {

...

  if ( temp.length() == input.length() ) {
    break;
  }
}
```

That loop will *never* terminate in the `for` statement. You might as well do it this way:

```
while( temp.length() < input.length() ) {
...
}
```

Once that's all working correctly, you should look into iterators.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string transformer(const std::string& input) {

    std::string res(input.length(), '0');

    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); ++i) {
        res[i] = input[ i % 2 == 0 ? input.length() - (i/2) - 1 : (i/2) ];
    }

    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This function just walks two indices toward the center until they meet or pass each other. The last `if` block handles the case of an odd length input string. It works for all your test cases on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/aRKjo)

```
std::string transformer(const std::string& input)
{
    std::string temp;
    int i = 0;
    int j = input.length() - 1;

    while (i < j) {
        temp += input[j--];
        temp += input[i++];
    }
    if (i == j) {
        temp += input[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `if (input[m] == input[n])` will make sure that if the first and last characters are the same, it immediately quits after the first character is processed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this with `std::string::iterator` and `std::string::reverse_iterator`:

```
auto it = input.begin();
auto rit = input.rbegin();
std::string temp;

for (size_t i = 0; i < input.length()/2; ++i) {
    temp += *rit++;
    temp += *it++;
}
```

The logic for handling empty and odd-length input is left for you to do, shouldn't be too hard. (Input of length 1 is also a special case)

Answer (score 0):

I would use pointers instead of indexes to do this.

So you have a pointer the reading the edges and you keep swapping them with each iteration.

It will also make it faster.

I think this should work, but I can't remember how to make an array of const char pointers. Can anyone help me with that step?

```
string transformer(string input) {

     std::string temp;

     const char *front, *back;

     for (*front = input.c_str(), *back = front + input.length() - 1; front < back ; front++, back--) {
        temp += *back;
        temp += *front;
     }

     if (front == back)
        temp += *front;


     return temp;

}
```

(using the same method as @Blastfurnace, but skipping unnecessary indexes.)

Comment: This is impressive, in the sense juggling razors blindfolded is impressive.

Comment: Its short and the algorithm is exactly the same like a person would solve it.

Comment: Have you tried to compile or run this? With g++, I get errors on the declaration of `source` and the statement `source++`

Comment: @Blastfurnace its been years since ive last used a c++ compile. Will have a look at it, thanks.

Comment: @Blastfurnace okay this is running now.

Comment: It's not correct for even-length strings. [Link to test on ideone.com](http://ideone.com/YEmUo)

Comment: @Blastfurnace thanks again. I was to confident with the end clause there. I will think of something else that or delete this answer :(

Comment: The method in my answer isn't that different from yours, I just use indices instead of pointers. To be honest, at first glance, your code looks too tricky and fragile. I try to write code as simple and clear as possible. It's easier to reason about and easier for a compiler to optimize.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I personally find it easier to deal with pointers rather than indexes and its performance, but yea doing both ends in one iteration is good idea.

Comment: @Blastfurnace http://ideone.com/CSUvb it doesn't look so tricky with your method, but pointers. The good thing here is that the compiler doesn't need to optimize. Without optimization, you code would need to do pointer arithmetic for your indexes i and j at every iteration. Using pointers directly avoids this and uses less memory.